# ember-data making extra GET requests for belongsTo relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

My model data is being properly serialized and deserialized, but it ends up making extra requests for data that is already present, side-loaded in the JSON document. (Those requests fail because we don't have an endpoint for those objects)

For example:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/2/apps/53fde960cc095d0e0000002d/in_app_message_buttons/5405c098cc095d88e800000b 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm using Rails and ember-data. On the rails side, my serializer looks like this:

```
class PopUpMessageVariationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true  #model not properly deserialized till we added this
  has_one     :cta_button, :root => :in_app_message_button
  has_one     :cancel_button,  :root => :in_app_message_button
  has_one :headline, :root => :message_labels
  has_one :body, :root => :message_labels
end
```

My ember-data model looks like this:

```
PopUpMessageVariation = InAppMessageVariation.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
 ctaButton: DS.belongsTo('in_app_message_button'),
 cancelButton: DS.belongsTo('in_app_message_button'),
 headline: DS.belongsTo('message_label'),
    body: DS.belongsTo('message_label'),
});
```

And the ember serializer:

```
PopUpMessageVariationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
      headline: { embedded: 'always' },
      body: { embedded: 'always' },
      ctaButton: { embedded: 'always' },
      cancelButton: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});
```

I tried adding {async: false} to the relations, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ember.Validations.Mixin](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) is causing the rogue requests! I need to take it out or patch it.

However, I've noticed the ember-validations doesn't explicitly make any server calls - so the problem could still be in ember-data. One issue is that ember-validations attempts to validate the models before they have their relations loaded because it fires on init.

[Locally I've patched ember-validations to prevent it from firing on init as described in this github issue.](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations/issues/152)